# How do you wrap validation for a function within another function?

Tags: java, function, validation, design-patterns, return

Say, for example, you have a bunch of functions that all need to check for login validation. To begin with, it looks something like:

```
public Response createThing(){
   if(!validLogin(httpRequest, uriInfo)){
      return Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN);
   }

   //Do the function
}
```

That first block of code exists at the top of every service call, but I don't know how to wrap it into another function because it contains a return statement. I would like something similar to the following:

```
public Response createThing(){
   validateLogin(httpRequest, uriInfo);

   //Do the function
}
```

or

```
public Response createThing(){
   //Implied check somehow?

   //Do the function
}
```

I'm sure there's some pattern or convention out there that people use. Thanks.

Comment: Is this JavaEE?  You would use a filter for this.  I believe the general pattern is called "Intercepting Filter"

Comment: would it be ok to handle it as a exception that is thrown by your validation method and is handled in your wrapper method? With a custom exception for example?

Comment: For this specific case, yes it's JavaEE, but I have the same question for similar underlying calls as well (like validating input to not be null.). I will have a look at Intercepting Filter though, thank you.

Comment: @Rhayene Throwing an exception and handling it in the wrapper method would still bring me back to my original problem of the return statement inside the wrapper method, the only difference being the try/catch block vs. an if statement I think.

Comment: what would you return if the input was valid? As I read it now - you would only return something if something was invalid - so I would not return at all but contain the information in an exception. But I can be wrong :)

Comment: What I mean to say, is that I would still need to catch and handle the exception for an invalid login. The code to handle the catch block would have the same problem.

Comment: @Rhayene I see what you meant now by throwing exceptions; I misunderstood. Throwing an exception works in some cases (like the other cases I mentioned to puhlen, throwing would work, yes), but in some other ones I can't just throw the exception out (for example, in the above case in my question I would expose what technologies we use server side). However, that might just be a webservice specific question (like how puhlen mentioned Intercepting Filters), and throwing exceptions might just be the way to go in other cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from *Java 8*, functions are considered first class citizens. This allows you to reuse code in a way you never could before. You can create a template method that contains a fixed part and a variable part as shown below :

```
public <T,U,R extends Response> R doSomething(final BiFunction<T,U,R> funct,T input1,U input2){
  if(validLogin(input1, input2)) {//fixed part
     return funct.apply(input1,input2);//variable part
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems promising; I'll have to look into this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **AOP**, Aspect Oriented Programming.

Using AspectJ, or Spring, you can define "Advice" which gets applied before, after or around configured points in your code.

For example:

```
@Before("createThing(httpRequest, uriInfo)")
public void validate(HttpRequest request, UriInfo uriInfo) {
     if(!valid(request,uriInfo)) {
          throw new InvalidCreateThingException();
     }
}
```

This is very powerful and flexible, especially if you use `@Around` advice, which is somewhat more complicated to specify, but means you can both hook into the inputs of a method, and influence its outputs. You can configure AOP advice using wildcards, so it gets applied to any matching object/method.

A lot of Spring's "magic" is achieved using AOP. Both Spring and AspectJ provide good documentation.

Answer (score -2):

```
public Response validateLogin(){
   if(!validLogin(httpRequest, uriInfo)){
       return Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN);
   }
   return Responce.status(Response.Status.OK)
}


public Response createThing(){
   if(!validateLogin().equals(Response.status(Response.Status.OK)){
      return Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN);
   }

   //Do the function
}
```

Comment: That still brings me back to the same problem structurally, amongst other things. The first three lines of createThing() would still be duplicated.